# git add is adding files to staging area

Tags: git, github, git-svn, bitbucket

I am trying to commit some modified files to my git staging area with command `git add`. However the files are not adding to the staging area.

The below is the output of `git status`:-

```
  :~/Desktop/production-18-12-2013$ git status
    # On branch master
    # Changes not staged for commit:
    #   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    #
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/application.js~
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/controllers/app.js~
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/menu.js~
    #   deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/services/userAPI.js~
    #   deleted:    app/assets/stylesheets/application.css~
    #   deleted:    app/assets/stylesheets/safariwindows.css~
    #   deleted:    app/assets/stylesheets/windowsapplication.css~
    #   deleted:    app/controllers/appi_controller.rb~
    #   deleted:    config/initializers/event_machine.rb~
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-042a070a3832c680df06e7ea031766e7.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-042a070a3832c680df06e7ea031766e7.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-17a2431c4f2227103425cec76c5b4507.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-17a2431c4f2227103425cec76c5b4507.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-26253c7e7241dfc73bddea7e43ece04c.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-26253c7e7241dfc73bddea7e43ece04c.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-321c36234afb9e931f847afc9e15356a.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-321c36234afb9e931f847afc9e15356a.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-432a3132331e44e99dc825681de186fc.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-432a3132331e44e99dc825681de186fc.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-4ce91df18f6d02b72a2d4fd6288b7e27.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-4ce91df18f6d02b72a2d4fd6288b7e27.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-53f94195fd52dfe8bf42d8ce6f1d34ed.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-53f94195fd52dfe8bf42d8ce6f1d34ed.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-5a7c32b4917ea37959fce75e96cda547.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-5a7c32b4917ea37959fce75e96cda547.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-8c5483b4973e96b28612ecb18e4c3942.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-8c5483b4973e96b28612ecb18e4c3942.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-a81a1274e455dbead72c22762b3c2a34.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-a81a1274e455dbead72c22762b3c2a34.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-ceed710b515059aeb59a02f72b0b4dc3.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-ceed710b515059aeb59a02f72b0b4dc3.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-ddabc637f1d7ed563483b991094b9692.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-ddabc637f1d7ed563483b991094b9692.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-e47883af638c3eaeb828901746dc14a0.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-e47883af638c3eaeb828901746dc14a0.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-e6c199f7b655bba181fdbabb83702335.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-e6c199f7b655bba181fdbabb83702335.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-f546c5ac258ae2f4b2051bd5c09ad581.js
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-f546c5ac258ae2f4b2051bd5c09ad581.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-f813e11ed5210d25e039736f7300b550.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application-f813e11ed5210d25e039736f7300b550.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application.js.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application2-6a76bc78fbb8e38bfeb101cd769b3978.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application2-6a76bc78fbb8e38bfeb101cd769b3978.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application2.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/application2.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/ie-6051136603bde9acd2baf93c330af904.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/ie-6051136603bde9acd2baf93c330af904.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/ie.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/ie.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/jquery.min-2df7da5d7895835e8cc10130711ba4a6.map
    #   deleted:    public/assets/jquery.min.map
    #   deleted:    public/assets/manifest.yml
    #   deleted:    public/assets/rails-aa8aea913cd3b23f0cdf2a950a48069a.png
    #   deleted:    public/assets/rails.png
    #   deleted:    public/assets/safariwindows-64111c331f7b5da9cc8cbb61b70edba5.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/safariwindows-64111c331f7b5da9cc8cbb61b70edba5.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/safariwindows.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/safariwindows.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/safariwindows2-54679b90e662ef9657c0bac13cbfca79.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/safariwindows2-54679b90e662ef9657c0bac13cbfca79.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/safariwindows2.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/safariwindows2.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/untitled
    #   deleted:    public/assets/windowsapplication-ef6d76bdf635d72d487ee4c51cea9b27.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/windowsapplication-ef6d76bdf635d72d487ee4c51cea9b27.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/windowsapplication.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/windowsapplication.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/windowsapplication2-85d68c3cd237247123bb47428dc8a138.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/windowsapplication2-85d68c3cd237247123bb47428dc8a138.css.gz
    #   deleted:    public/assets/windowsapplication2.css
    #   deleted:    public/assets/windowsapplication2.css.gz
    #
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

and then write the command `git add`

But this is not helping me and `git status` is giving me the above output(same)

Is this because of `git-update-index-assume-unchange` command which i had put before git status

If so then how to solve this issue.I have gone to various forums but not getting the output.

Please help me with this

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to remove multiple intermittent files generated during from your repo, and have deleted each of these files manually and are now trying to commit the change.

If that is the case you need to use `git rm` to remove these.

In case you want to remove specific file, do git `rm path/to/file`

If you want to remove all files of a particular pattern, like `*~`, `~.gz`, use `git rm -r "*~" "~.gz" "~.png"`

Also, I would suggest adding these patterns to your `.gitignore` file so that these files are not added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any changed files. You've deleted files from the tree. Use `git rm` to stage files for deletion (as it tells you) and then commit.

Answer (score 0):

have you ever tried `git add --all`